# Retrieve a value from a Javascript object

Tags: javascript

How do I retrieve a value from the object below?

```
var recipe= {};
recipe[0, 'prodmem_active.tpoint_prod[0].setpoint'] = 1600;
recipe[0, 'prodmem_active.tpoint_prod[1].setpoint'] = 1300;
recipe[1, 'prodmem_active.tpoint_prod[0].setpoint'] = 1600;
recipe[1, 'prodmem_active.tpoint_prod[1].setpoint'] = 1300;
recipe[2, 'prodmem_active.tpoint_prod[0].setpoint'] = 1500;
recipe[2, 'prodmem_active.tpoint_prod[1].setpoint'] = 1200;
```

e.g. `alert(recipe[1]['prodmem_active.tpoint_prod[1].setpoint'])` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign the value correctly in the first place.

The comma operator evaluates as its right hand side.

This:

```
recipe[0, 'prodmem_active.tpoint_prod[0].setpoint'] = 1600;
```

Means the same as:

```
recipe['prodmem_active.tpoint_prod[0].setpoint'] = 1600;
```

You are trying to create a new object and then assign a value to one of the new objects properties.

```
recipe[0] = {};
recipe[0]['prodmem_active.tpoint_prod[0].setpoint'] = 1600;
```